# Can I bind a key to specific voice commands?

Tags: overwatch

Instead of having to use the voice command wheel every single time I want to disclose my Ultimate status, or just saying hello, or taunting, I have to press the command wheel button, hover over the selected option and let go.  Is there a way I can just bind one specific key to say Voice Line, or Taunt, or Need Healing?

Comment: @Timelord64 We could probably answer this from beta knowledge, at least. If it had that capability.

Comment: Ughhhhhh I hate Blizzard for causing this as a potential problem more than once for us.

Comment: Because if someone has knowledge of this they can actually contribute to it?  I don't need to play the beta to know how to use an ultimate, or how to sprint as Soldier 76, so I don't get why you assume that since the Beta is over, NOBODY on this EARTH will every figure out or can answer the question.

Comment: @Timelord64 Because I saw someone do it in a gameplay vid and they didn't disclose, in both the video and the comments how they did it. Besides, when did it become your position to judge the asker intent?

Comment: [Related](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8518/oh-look-its-unreleased-content-again)

Comment: Here's the thing: This is an extremely low-effort question because a single look at the Keyboard bindings screen (whatever Overwatch calls it) answers this question in a glance.

Comment: @Powerlord Except you used a UI screenshot from Closed Beta, and in the Open Beta UI I haven't seen such a command at all.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and clean up some of the comments here. @Timelord64, please stop resorting to personal insults and accusations. Judge the content based on the content, not on the user.

Comment: @O-O Wasn't my screenshot, but the Open Beta  had the same screen, but with a different background color.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes**. There is an option to bind keys to all of the voice commands. They are bound by default for ultimate status, need healing, and acknowledge. The rest are unbound by default. I have "group up" bound to <kbd>Y</kbd> in the following screenshot:

[image: Communication options menu]